# To read & write is what literacy is

Tags: verbs

Hope you all are doing well.

Please let me know if the following sentence is syntactically correct:

> The ability, skill and willingness to read & write is what literacy is.

Another question is about using *it* with the word *appreciate*. Which of the following sentence is correct?

> - I will appreciate if you answer the question; or
> - I will appreciate **it** if you answer the question.

Thanks

Comment: 2) Is conditional, and **appreciate** needs an object, so the first would be correct as *I would appreciate you answering the question.* 1) Seems grammatical but is not idiomatic nor semantically correct. *Literacy is the ability to read and write.* You don't need both 'ability' *and* 'skill' and it has nothing to do with willingness, which has more to do with the learning process than the end result.

Comment: Hi Weather, why is it not semantically correct? When we use the same structure with other sentences, they make sense. Take an example of an idiom, **It is what it is**. The word **it** in the idiom is replaced.

Comment: I think I explained that in the comment. Literacy is unrelated to willingness. You might be unwilling to read or write, but still be literate.

Comment: If we divide it into four quadrants, the first one would be a person who is literate and is willing to read and write, the second one would an unwilling person who is literate, the third one would be an illerate and unwilling person, and the last quadrant would have those who are are willing and illerate. Willingness plays an important to increase the literacy rate of the last quadrant.

Comment: Sorry, you are conflating it by introducing "literacy **rates**".

Comment: What's wrong with **rates**? The main idea will still be about literacy. Rate is just a ratio.

Comment: So you are asking about a literacy **program**? Literacy is the ability to read and write.

Comment: Yes Weather, the MLP program.

Comment: "The success (or effectiveness) of a literacy program is dependant on the ability, skill and willingness of those involved."

Answer (score 0):

It is syntactically correct.  You have a subject

> The ability, skill and willingness to read and write

This is treated as singular as it is an infinitive noun phrase (which are considered singular)

THen there is a linking verb it has the correct agreement with the subject

> is

THen there is a complement, another noun phrase, this time it is headed by "what"

> what literacy is

That makes a sentence.

As noted in comments, it doesn't seem to be true. You should omit willingness, and probably only mention "ability" since "skill" is redundant,

> The ability to read and write is what literacy is.

Comment: Thanks a lot James.